# on click functions being applied to all divs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two panels which are built using the same classes, but their content is slightly different. I have to hide and toggle classes depending on the options the user selects.

I've got the functionality working for the panels, but the issue is that the jQuery its being applied to both panels at the same time on click, which then stops the panels working how I would like. I only want the functions to be applied on click to that specific panel.

I've been reading and I thought that by using `(this)` would help fix this problem. Same as using `.each()`. But I've not been able to fix it.

---

**Updated**

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/210078/), showing how the panels currently work. *- new fiddle*

- User clicks on option 'everyday' within the '1.choose your range' section of the first panel
- This triggers option '2 . choose your style' to appear and '1.choose your range' section to hide in the first panel
- However when clicking on any of these options its being applied to the second panel also, which I do not want. The second panel should only animate when the user selects the options within that panel.

The panels shouldn't animate unless the user has selected an option within that specific panel.

Here is my jQuery Code:

```js
$('.price-colour li').on('click', function() {
  $('.price-colour li').not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})

$('.style-type').on('click', function() {
  $('.style-type').not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})

$('#basket-cart').on('click', function() {
  $('#popup-shopping').toggleClass('visible');
})

$('#popup-shopping__close-icon').on('click', function() {
  $('#popup-shopping').toggleClass('visible');
})

$('.edit-txt').on('click', function() {
  $('.range-item').not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).parents().find('.price-item-section').toggleClass('inactive');
  $(this).addClass('hidden');
  $(this).parents().find('.link-btn--solid').toggleClass('inactive');
})

$('.range-item').on('click', function() {
  $('.range-item').not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  $('.edit-txt').removeClass('hidden');
  $(this).parents().find('.price-item-section').toggleClass('inactive');
  $(this).parents().find('.link-btn--solid').toggleClass('inactive');
})
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.o-unlist {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.price-item {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.price-item-top {
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.price-item-section {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.price-item-section.inactive h3 {
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.price-item-section.inactive .price-range,
.price-item-section.inactive .price-detail,
.price-item-section.inactive .price-style,
.price-item-section.inactive .price-item-three {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.price-range {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  height: auto;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.price-item-three {
  padding: 15px 50px 0;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px -30px 0;
}

.price-style {
  margin-top: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  height: auto;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.price-style p {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
}

.style-type {
  opacity: 0.6;
  padding: 5px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.style-type.selected {
  opacity: 1;
}

.price-detail {
  margin-top: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  height: auto;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.price-colour {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 -7px 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

.price-colour li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 9px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
}

.price-colour li span {
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.price-colour li#pink span {
  background: pink;
}

.price-colour li#yellow span {
  background: yellow;
}

.price-colour li#black span {
  background: black;
}

.price-colour li#grey span {
  background: #999999;
}

.price-colour li.selected {
  border-color: #999999;
}

.price-size-guide {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  color: $monza;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.size-guide-icon {
  background: url(../images/size-guide-icon.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 25px;
  height: 12px;
  background-size: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#price-select {
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.radio-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
}

.radio-select {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.radio-select:first-child {
  margin-right: 43px;
}

.radio-select input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.radio-select input:checked~.radio-indicator {
  background: red;
}

.radio-select a {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.1rem;
  color: $heli;
  display: block;
  font-family: $grotesk;
  font-weight: $groreg;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.edit-txt {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: all;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.edit-txt.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.range-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 35px 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-item img {
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.range-item p {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: $grotesk;
  font-weight: $groreg;
}

.range-item.selected img {
  border-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      image in here

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">

      <div class="price-item">
        <div class="price-item-top">
          <h3 class="heading-price">Choose your bottoms</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="price-item-one price-item-section clearfix inactive">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <h3 class="heading-price float-left">1. choose your range: lace</h3>
            <span class="edit-txt float-right">edit</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="price-range o-unlist clearfix">
            <li id="lace" class="range-item selected">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x31" />
              <p>lace</p>
            </li>
            <li id="everyday" class="range-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x31" />
              <p>everday</p>
            </li>
            <li id="adventure" class="range-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x31" />
              <p>adventure</p>
            </li>
            <li id="slogan" class="range-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x31" />
              <p>slogan</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="price-item-two price-item-section clearfix">
          <h3 class="heading-price">2. choose your style</h3>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="price-style float-left">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 o-txt-center">
                  <div id="style-brief" class="style-type selected">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/63x40" width="63" />
                    <p>brief</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 o-txt-center">
                  <div id="style-thong" class="style-type">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/63x40" width="63" />
                    <p>thong</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price-detail float-right">
              <ul class="price-colour">
                <li id="pink" class="selected"><span></span></li>
                <li id="yellow"><span></span></li>
                <li id="black"><span></span></li>
                <li id="grey"><span></span></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="price-size-guide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-size-guide">
                redefining size guide <i class="size-guide-icon"></i>
              </div>
              <select id="price-select">
                <option value="small">small (8/10)</option>
                <option value="medium">medium (12/14)</option>
                <option value="large">large (16/18)</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="price-item-three clearfix">
            <label class="radio-select float-left">buy once £28
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="checked"/>
                    <div class="radio-indicator"></div>
                  </label>
            <label class="radio-select float-right">get monthly £24
                    <a href="#" class="how-sub" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-subscription">how subscription works</a>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
                    <div class="radio-indicator"></div>
                  </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- price item-->
    </div>
    <!--col lg 5-->
  </div>
  <!-- row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      image in here

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="price-item">
        <div class="price-item-top">
          <h3 class="heading-price">Choose your top</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="price-item-one price-item-section clearfix">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <h3 class="heading-price float-left">1. choose your range: lace</h3>
            <span class="edit-txt float-right">edit</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="price-range o-unlist clearfix">
            <li id="lace" class="range-item selected">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x31" />
              <p>lace</p>
            </li>
            <li id="everyday" class="range-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x31" />
              <p>everday</p>
            </li>
            <li id="adventure" class="range-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x31" />
              <p>adventure</p>
            </li>
            <li id="slogan" class="range-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x31" />
              <p>slogan</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="price-item-two price-item-section clearfix inactive">
          <h3 class="heading-price">2. choose your style</h3>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="price-style float-left">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 o-txt-center">
                  <div id="style-bra" class="style-type selected">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/63x40" width="63" />
                    <p>bra</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 o-txt-center">
                  <div id="style-bralette" class="style-type">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/63x40" width="63" />
                    <p>bralette</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price-detail float-right">
              <ul class="price-colour">
                <li id="pink" class="selected"><span></span></li>
                <li id="yellow"><span></span></li>
                <li id="black"><span></span></li>
                <li id="grey"><span></span></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="price-size-guide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-size-guide">
                redefining size guide <i class="size-guide-icon"></i>
              </div>
              <select id="price-select">
                <option value="small">small (8/10)</option>
                <option value="medium">medium (12/14)</option>
                <option value="large">large (16/18)</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="price-item-three clearfix">
            <label class="radio-select float-left">buy once £28
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="checked"/>
                    <div class="radio-indicator"></div>
                  </label>
            <label class="radio-select float-right">get monthly £24
                    <a href="#" class="how-sub" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-subscription">how subscription works</a>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
                    <div class="radio-indicator"></div>
                  </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <!--col lg 5-->
      </div>
      <!-- row-->

</section>
```

Comment: Please let us know your expectations. It it quite confusing

Comment: I've updated answer and fiddle so hopefully more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parents()` selector is selecting ALL parents.  Use `closest()` with a selector to only toggle children beneath that element.

```
    $(this).closest('.price-item').find('.price-item-section').toggleClass('inactive');
```

Comment: But this would been only the first panel is animated no? Where as I need both panels to toggle the classes but only when the button within their specific panel is clicked.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question with new fiddle if that helps.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.price-item').find('.price-item-section')` seems to work.